# Can you do a no-hold transfer in Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-connect

I have a deal I'm working on designing to deploy Amazon Connect to a contact center with 200 agents. Their volume is 95% outbound, and 5% inbound voice only. Their account managers receive qualified leads in their CRM (in this case SalesForce Service Cloud) and upon opening up the lead would like to click on the phone number in SalesForce and use the StartOutboundVoiceContact API to call the customer. Once they have the customer on the phone they would like to be able to do a no-hold consultative transfer to a different department that is staffed by loan officers and want to be able to do the following:

Agent A clicks on a button in the CCP or SF that places a new outbound call to a queue staffed with loan officers. Want to notify Agent B (the loan officer) that they are being reserved for a call from the account management department and then they "accept" the inbound call and Agent A is then able to bridge the two parties together and complete the transfer.

Is there a way to use DynamoDB, Custom CCP, and Lambda to build this type of solution?

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for a "cold transfer"? This is doable using the Amazon Connect Streams API. Good blog post [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/making-cold-transfers-using-the-amazon-connect-streams-api/) that goes through several transfer scenarios.

Comment: A cold transfer would not work in this use case. The customer needs a transfer option that allows agents to pass the inbound sales lead to another sales rep while maintaining an active conversation with the buyer, all without hold music or ring-throughs. So instead, the system automatically looks for another available agent and connects a three-way call. The originating agent can disconnect once the two parties are joined.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be possible to do a "no-hold" transfer for merging a call. Amazon Connect will always place someone on hold before joining a connection together for a conference call.

However, if you really wanted to bypass Amazon Connect's system, you could try the following( Using Amazon Connect Stream API ):

1. Silent the music for the queue that you are sending the call through.
2. Customer will be placed on hold for a few seconds.
3. Immediately merge the call onto the current call(Using Amazon Connect Stream API)
4. If agent connects within 7 seconds then current agent will terminate the call.

The one thing you can't get rid of would be the ringing to the third-party agent. Additionally, there may be some type of delay between the customer being placed on hold and being merged onto the current call. So, this may not be 100% ideal for your situation.